# DRF serializers, different field type

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to archive such situations using drf serializers, when field can be different type.

I'm using such API, and field *positions* can be both **dict** or **list**, depends on content.

How the serializer should look like. I've tried something like

```
class PositionCreateSerializer(SapPositionSerializer):
    positions = serializers.ReadOnlyField(required=False)
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). For example:

```
class PositionCreateSerializer(SapPositionSerializer):
    positions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_positions(self, obj):
       if obj.content == 'list':
           return list(...) # list of some values
       return dict(...) # a dict
```

**Alternatively**, you can create a new DRF field and override [`to_representation`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example_1) method. Like this:

```
class PositionsField(serializers.ReadOnlyField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
       if value == 'something list':
           return list()
       return dict()


class PositionCreateSerializer(SapPositionSerializer):
    positions = PositionsField()
```